# Typescript compiler error when comparing mutable enum member variables

Tags: typescript, enums

I am getting the error:

```
TS2365: Operator '===' cannot be applied to types 'ExampleState.Unsaved' and 'ExampleState.Saving'.
```

When comparing an enum against a mutable member variable:

```
enum ExampleState {
    Unset = -1,
    Unsaved = 0,
    Saving = 1,
    Saved = 2
}

class Example {

    private state : ExampleState = ExampleState.Unset;

    public Save() {
        if (this.state === ExampleState.Unsaved) {
            this.BeginSaving();
            while (this.state === ExampleState.Saving) {  // !error!
                this.CommitSave();
            }
        }
    }

    private BeginSaving() {
        this.state = ExampleState.Saving;
    }

    private CommitSave() {
        this.state = ExampleState.Saved;
    }
}
```

The real example is an async method that performs multiple attempts at saving -
 this has been simplified to just illustrate the error.

Typescript doesn't seem to understand that this variable is mutable and overly aggressively assuming that it is not being changed. Why is this happening and what is the work-around?

Comment: You could use `while (this.state as any === ExampleState.Saving)` as a workaround. But I suggest you to [submit the case to the TypeScript team](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues).

Comment: Same suggestion, although I'd rather do:

`while (this.state as ExampleState === ExampleState.Saving)`

Comment: There is a open issues about that: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Comment: In the issue posted by @Magu, there is [another workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998#issuecomment-235963457). I think it's the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [know issus from the Control flow analysis](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998).

As [another workaround](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998#issuecomment-235963457) you can create a wrapper method for the state property. (Thanks @Paleo)

Visit the [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=enum%20ExampleState%20%7B%0D%0A%20Unset%20%3D%20-1%2C%0D%0A%20Unsaved%20%3D%200%2C%0D%0A%20Saving%20%3D%201%2C%0D%0A%20Saved%20%3D%202%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Example%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20private%20state%20%3A%20ExampleState%20%3D%20ExampleState.Unset%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20private%20State()%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20return%20this.state%3B%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20public%20Save()%20%7B%0D%0A%20if%20(this.State()%20%3D%3D%3D%20ExampleState.Unsaved)%20%7B%0D%0A%20this.BeginSaving()%3B%0D%0A%20while%20(this.State()%20%3D%3D%3D%20ExampleState.Saving)%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20this.CommitSave()%3B%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20private%20BeginSaving()%20%7B%0D%0A%20this.state%20%3D%20ExampleState.Saving%3B%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20private%20CommitSave()%20%7B%0D%0A%20this.state%20%3D%20ExampleState.Saved%3B%0D%0A%20%7D%0D%0A%7D).

```
enum ExampleState {
    Unset = -1,
    Unsaved = 0,
    Saving = 1,
    Saved = 2
}

class Example {

    private state : ExampleState = ExampleState.Unset;

    private State() { 
        return this.state;
    }

    public Save() {
        if (this.State() === ExampleState.Unsaved) {
            this.BeginSaving();
            while (this.State() === ExampleState.Saving) { 
                this.CommitSave();
            }
        }
    }

    private BeginSaving() {
        this.state = ExampleState.Saving;
    }

    private CommitSave() {
        this.state = ExampleState.Saved;
    }
}
```